# Проблема с установкой Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Установил jupyter используя команду в командной строке `pip install jupyter`. После          этого пытался запустить, используя команду `jupyter notebook`, но вышло следующее

```
C:\Users\pc>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", lin
e 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", lin
e 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\jupyter-no
tebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\
notebook\notebookapp.py", line 36, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\
jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\
jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\
jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\
jinja2\utils.py", line 647, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\
markupsafe\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from markupsafe._compat import text_type, string_types, int_types, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'
```

Ввёл `pip install markupsafe`, но вышло, что он уже установлен.

Comment: Постарайтесь пожалуйста оформлять вопрос как текст, а не картинками. Даже в cmd есть возможность скопировать вывод. Здесь не художественная галерея.

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Мне когда-то помог откат в 3.5 с подобными ошибками.

Comment: Откат помог. Спасибо